# CSS id and classes

Tags: html, css

I have an `id` right now which I call on different pages, but never on the same page so it works. Would the best practice be to make it a `class` because its being called on different pages, but not more than once on the different page.

For example, say I have my home page. I call the id `test` once there. then maybe on my about page I call the id `test` there again. I will never need to call the id `test` more than once on a page. Should I use an id or class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntactically, there is nothing wrong with using ID so long as you only use that ID once per page.  For CSS, that is the purpose of an ID.  However, I don't know if there's any point unless you intend to also use that ID in JavaScript.

If you instead use a class, it will provide more flexibility down the road if you end up using the "test" ID more than once per page.  I know you don't intend to now, but you might later.

Comment: IDs are faster for css rules (in some browsers), and ID can serve as `#` anchors within the page.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ID. There is no reason to change to a class just because it's the same on different pages.

Answer (score 1):

If the identifier will only be used once on a single page then using an ID is appropriate. If you want to apply styles to that element that would also apply to another element/set of elements then it might also be appropriate to add a class as well as the ID.

Answer (score 1):

`id` is appropriate here. `id`s should be used to name a specific element on a page, whereas `class`es are for things that could occur anywhere on the page.

thus there's an important semantic difference.

but my personal advice is to remember that it's all there for you to use and you can use it however you want. there are lots of ambiguous cases for this.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is only one instance of an element with a given `id` you're fine using `id`. Beyond the requirement that `ids` are unique, whether to use `class` or `id` is mostly a matter preference. Selecting elements with `id` with scripting is faster than matching `class` and much easier if you're not using a library with a selector component like jQuery. I tend to use `id` for the main containers on a page.